# Showing content when "Like page" without accepting application

Tags: javascript, button, facebook-like

How Microsoft did it on their fan page, showing content on press "Like" button without having to accept application? And it remembers your "Like" for later visits.

http://www.facebook.com/Microsoft/app_190106037733438

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is canvas application, [SIGNED_REQUEST](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) is being sent.